# I am getting "Missing number, treated as zero" error. How can I get rid of it?

Tags: latex

I can not get proper layout. I want these to be horizontally aligned but even I have properly installed \usepackage{subcaption} without any \usepackage{subfigures} package, I still get "Missing number, treated as zero. Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted) overfull \hbox (17.28003 pt too wide" error on this line:

> \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,]{shapes.jpg} 
\caption{Caption1}
\label{fig:subim1}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{shapes2.jpg}
\caption{Caption 2}
\label{fig:subim2}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Caption for this figure with two images}
\label{fig:image2}
\end{figure}
```

[image: problem]

NOTE: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/519518/subfigures-with-captions-for-thesis-using-subfigure-package         kind people in here solved it. There is some clash between two packages. I stopped using subcaptions and started using subfigures package instead. I can not get rid of subfigures package because it is embedded in my .cls file.

Comment: please make a compilable [mre] including all necessary packages etc.

Comment: If I guess enough packages to make your code fragment compilable, it works just fine.